# How to apply border around shape created by child divs

Tags: css, border, box-shadow

I have a number of overlapping divs which I am treating as a single shape. The shape needs to be semi-opaque, so I have housed them in a parent div and applied opacity to the parent div like so:

```css
#top_housing_bg_div {
  opacity: 0.55;
  filter: alpha(opacity=55);
}

#top_bg_div {
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 14px - 9px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 14px - 9px);
  width: calc(100% - 14px - 9px);
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo_bg_div {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_housing_bg_div">
  <div id="top_bg_div">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="logo_bg_div">
    <!--empty for now-->
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to have a *single* border that follows the outline of that semi-opaque shape (as opposed to each sub-div having its own border which encroaches into the semi-opaque body of the other elements) and I have tried - and failed - to do so by using box-shadow on the parent div, setting border etc.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you have an image of what this is supposed to look like?

Comment: Frankly, this should like something an SVG would be ideal for.

Comment: I've edited the snippet so you can see the shape I'm working with @Paulie_D

Comment: Yeah...probably not going to be done with standard CSS. I'd strongly recommend SVG.

Comment: I'm looking to use this as a semi-opaque background for a menu - an SVG wouldn't be scalable/responsive would it? Do you know of a better way to solve the issue of creating a semi-opaque background for such a menu element?

Comment: SVG's are absolutely responsive...and the S stands for Scalable.

Comment: Ha! Showing my ignorance there, sorry. I don't suppose you could alter my example to use an SVG, or just point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already started adding specific values ( height, width, position etc. ) , you can use a `pseudo-element` to achieve this goal by adding it on top of the smaller div, and so, covering the border of the div.

See below ( hope i understood correctly what you wanted )

```css
body {
margin:0
}

#logo_bg_div:before {
  height: 20px;
  top: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  content: "";
}


#top_housing_bg_div {
  opacity: 0.55;
  filter: alpha(opacity=55);
}

#top_bg_div {
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 14px - 9px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 14px - 9px);
  width: calc(100% - 14px - 9px);
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#logo_bg_div {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="top_housing_bg_div">
  <div id="top_bg_div">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="logo_bg_div">
    <!--empty for now-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks really good, it's definitely close to what I'm after - would you be able to close off the slight gap in the red outline though?

Comment: @HomerPlata well you need to change the height of the `before` . and position it as you want on top of the div . You can add `background:blue` to the `before` so you can see exactly where it is, and ' play ' with it's height and top position

Comment: @HomerPlata glad i could help. As a side note, i would also take Paulie's advice and look into svgs .